# Создание разреженного файла

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система

Нужно создать файл, у которого в свойствах указанный размер будет больше размера диска на котором он находится.

Создаю разреженный файл:

```
fsutil file createnew file1 262144;
fsutil sparse setflag file1;
fsutil sparse setrange file1 0 262144;
```

Нашла, что нужно сделать дамп, затем в hex-редакторе сделать изменения и восстановить файл. Делаю дамп с помощью NTFS BackupRead Dumper, но он пишет (null).

Comment: Зачем вы портите свои вопросы?

Answer (score 1):

Да легко.

```
SparseFile.exe g:\sparsefile.txt 100000000000
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [скомпилированный exe проги](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/zenden/zenden-image-uploader/SparseFile.exe) (прямая ссылка, подписано моей цифровой подписью).

Исходники:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE CreateSparseFile(LPCTSTR lpSparseFileName)
{
    // Use CreateFile as you would normally - Create file with whatever flags 
    //and File Share attributes that works for you
    DWORD dwTemp;

    HANDLE hSparseFile = CreateFile(lpSparseFileName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (hSparseFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return hSparseFile;

    DeviceIoControl(hSparseFile,
        FSCTL_SET_SPARSE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        &dwTemp,
        NULL);
    return hSparseFile;
}

DWORD SetSparseRange(HANDLE hSparseFile, LONGLONG start, LONGLONG size)
{
    // Specify the starting and the ending address (not the size) of the 
    // sparse zero block
    FILE_ZERO_DATA_INFORMATION fzdi;
    fzdi.FileOffset.QuadPart = start;
    fzdi.BeyondFinalZero.QuadPart = start + size;
    // Mark the range as sparse zero block
    DWORD dwTemp;
    SetLastError(0);
    BOOL bStatus = DeviceIoControl(hSparseFile,
        FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA,
        &fzdi,
        sizeof(fzdi),
        NULL,
        0,
        &dwTemp,
        NULL);
    if (bStatus) return 0; //Sucess
    else {
        DWORD e = GetLastError();
        return(e); //return the error value
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "USAGE: SparseFile filename size" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try {
        ULONGLONG size = std::stoull(argv[2]);
        HANDLE h = CreateSparseFile(argv[1]);
        if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to create file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if (SetSparseRange(h, 0, size) != 0) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to set sparse range" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        LARGE_INTEGER seek;
        seek.QuadPart = size;
        if (!SetFilePointerEx(h, seek, 0, 0)) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to seek to desired offset" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        SetEndOfFile(h);
        CloseHandle(h);
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```